# wxPython & pyGame Assignment

Tags: python, wxpython, pygame

I'm actually in need of your help and advice here on my assignment that I am working on. First of all, I was task to do a program that runs langton's ant simulation. For that, I've managed to get the source code (from snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/5143) and edited it accordingly to my requirements. This was done and ran in pygame module extension. In addition, my task requires a GUI to interface for users to run and navigate through the screens effectively with the langton's ant program running. I used wxPython with the help of an IDE called BOA constructor to create the frames, buttons, textboxes, etc. Basically, all the stuff needed in the interfaces.

However, I've ran into some problems listed below:

- Found problem integrating pyGame with wxPython.

  On this note, I've research the internet for answers and tutorials where I found out from website:  wiki.wxpython.org/IntegratingPyGame  & aspn.activestate.com/ASPN/Mail/Message/wxpython-users/3178042. I understand from the sites that integrating pyGame with wxPython will be a difficult task where it has caused common problems like the inability to placing other controls into the frames as the pyGame application will cover the entire panel. I really hope that you can clarify my doubts on this and advise me on the path that I should take from here. Therefore, I ask the following questions:
- Is it feasible to integrate pyGame with wxPython?
- If it is not feasible to integrate pyGame with wxPython, what other alternatives do I have to create a GUI interface integrating pyGame into it. If so how do I go about?
- If it is possible to go about integrating pyGame with wxPython, how do I go about doing so?

Really need you guys opinion on this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the page for you: [pygame GUI discussion](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/gui)

To sum it up: Don't use any standard GUI stuff together with pygame. It might work, but it's most definitely gonna annoy you big time. Also on this page, there's a discussion of various different GUI libraries available which work directly in pygame. It sounds like you only need some standard widgets, so you should be up and running in no time with one of these.

Comment: Hey Frank, thanks for your answer. On that note, have you come across any IDE for OcempGUI? Something like BOA constructor.

Comment: No I haven't heard of any IDEs. These pygame GUI packages probably are not popular enough for people investing time into developing an IDE.